# How do I cast if the "to-cast" class is a string?

Tags: java

This form of cast is okay:

```
((CastTo)this).getStates();
```

but I have:

```
Class<? extends CastTo> aClass = this.getClass();
((whatToWriteHere"CastTo"DoesntWork)this).getStates();
```

How would I cast the result?  What would I use to cast with a `Class` object?

Comment: Doesn't work with what result?

Comment: what to write instead of "whatToWriteHere"CastTo"DoesntWork"? :)

Comment: Why `CastTo` doesn't work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Class<? extends CastTo> aClass = this.getClass();
aClass.cast(this).getStates();
```